# Rpi4b -> Use Serial HC-12 SI4463 Transceiver to send to Generic RF outlets and 433 switches

Tags: gpio, python, serial, radio

Raspberry Pi4B

Hi, I am using a 433 MHZ TX/RX kit connected via GPIO pin 27 for receive and GPIO pin 22 to send signals to my RF power outlets and receive signals from my 433mhz Wireless Magnetic Door Window sensors.

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/RF-433-MHZ-Raspberry-Pi/) which is using the `rpi-rf` python package to communicate with the receiver and sender.

So my setup is the following:

[image]

Signals that I receive and send follow this `protocol`:

```
Decimal code to send
Protocol (Default: 1)
Pulselength (Default: 350)
Codelength (Default: 24)
rfdevice.tx_code(4588145,1 , 350, 24)
```

So if I receive a value from my *433Mhz openCloseDetectors* the rpi-rf_receive.py will print a number like this `51875481`. And If I want to start and stop my *433MhzPowerOutlets* I use the `rpi-rf_send` with a numeric argument like `4588145`

**Everything works but now I want to use the HC-12 SI4463 Transceiver to send and receive 433 Mhz Signals from my *433Mhz openCloseDetectors* and to my *433MhzPowerOutlets***

I assume the serial Protocol is totally different than what my devices and `rpi-rf` python package are using.

But I am already failing at the first step:

1.) I connected the [HC-12 SI4463 Transceiver](https://opencircuit.shop/product/hc12-si4463-433mhz-transceiver-module-long) to my Rpi4b pins:
[image]

```
VCC => +5V  GND => GND
SET => tried GND and not connected
RXD => GPIO14 (UART0_TXD)
TXD => GPIO15 (UART0_RXD)
```

2.) I enabled the serial port via Raspi-Config ( after a reboot I say this new entry in my /boot/config.txt -> `enable_uart=1` )

3.) Since I have only one HC-12 module my first challenge is to find out if the module is properly connected and working. I thought if I send something with the HC-12 Module, i can receive it with my
*rpi-rf_receive.py* connected to the `433 MHZ RX kit GPIO pin27`. I use this python script to send to the HC-12  via the serial console:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import serial
ser = serial.Serial ('/dev/serial0')    #Open named port
ser.baudrate = 9600                     #Set baud rate to 9600
ser.write(str.encode('Hello'))                         #Send back the received data
ser.close()
```

But my receiver is not picking up anything. I Assumed that because of the different protocols that the received result some nonsense but at least that something will be received.

**So my question: Has anyone an idea how to test my HC-12 module and is it possible to use the HC-12 module to receive codes from my *433Mhz openCloseDetectors***

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I must vote to close it because I don't feel it's actually "on topic" for this SE. You might try the [EE SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), or [Amateur Radio SE](https://ham.stackexchange.com/), or perhaps best - contact the vendor's tech support.